# htaccess file properly detects missing file from root directory but does not detect missing subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file that I'm using to catch when a requested image doesn't exist so I can make one. The file properly detects a missing image when requested from the directory the .htaccess file is in. But, if I request an image from a subdirectory that technically does not exist, .htaccess does not send me to my image handler. Can someone help me match any subdirectory that does not exist?

Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .(jpg|jpeg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ missingimage.php?img=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That .htaccess file is placed in a folder called "uploads". So for example, my uploads folder also has oranges.jpg.

The following url will correctly pass the request to missingimage.php:

> http://localhost/uploads/oranges_asdf.jpg

The following url will **NOT** correctly pass the request to missingimage.php, but instead returns a standard 404 from apache:

> http://localhost/uploads/not_a_real_directory/oranges.jpg

How can I modify my htaccess to catch requests to directories that don't exist and still pass them to my image handler? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

REQUEST_FILENAME doesn't actually contain the full absolutely path if the request doesn't exist. My theory on this without actually digging into httpd core code would be that it's thinking we've come far enough to know that the request isn't actually there so let's stop looking.

i.e. if you request /uploads/fake/test.jpg it'll REQUEST_FILENAME contains /path/to/uploads/fake and won't actually continue to append /test.jpg on there, but does when you do /path/to/uploads/test.jpg because test.jpg is the termination of where it knows the request doesn't exist. Even if this isn't the reason why httpd stops the string there you have plenty of other variables that can help you.

This rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

is ridiculously popular right now for this trick of creating a dispatcher for MVC frameworks and does actually work, since /path/to/uplaods/fake is niether a file nor a directory and will send your request to your image dispatcher.

Here's the real fix for your extension matching condition... you need to get the REQUEST_URI because it will contain what the user actually requested (/uploads/fake/test.jpg) including the file extension and you can us it in your third RewriteCond to match the file extension. Since we're going to use that for the third rule, I cleaned up your first two to match.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[A-Za-z0-9\/_-]+\/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ missingimage.php?img=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I cleaned up your match on the file name as you were matching all sorts of bullshit with that leading period which is actually (when un-escaped) telling the preg match engine to match anything. So, backslash period will make preg match an actually period.

I also cleaned up the match on the first half to the request uri to include /alpha/num/directories_with/underscores-and-dashes/followed/by/alpha-num_filenames.jpg|jpeg|gif, feel free to remove that if you don't want it.